# How can I simulate filtered Gaussian noise in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, signals

How can I find the frequency component of Gaussian noise in MATLAB and then filter it to obtain Gaussian noise with its bandwidth?

```
Fs = 100;
d = fdesign.lowpass('Fp,Fst,Ap,Ast',6,10,0.5,40,Fs);
B = design(d);
%// create white Gaussian noise the length of your signal
x = randn(1000,1);
%// create the band-limited Gaussian noise
y = filter(B,x);
```

Comment: Your title and your problem description have nothing to do with each other.  Your title indicates that you have no idea how to generate Gaussian noise, yet your problem description asks to determine the PSD of the noise profile and filtering on that.  Which is it?

Comment: @gariepy its not it's.

Comment: @rayryeng:  Yeah my bad, I realized right after I submitted that one...SO is very anti-"editing for typos" though, so I don't think I can get that one change approved.

Comment: Aha no worries at all :) @gariepy. Just wanted to point out that minor typo. The other edits are quite fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add white Gaussian noise to a signal with:

```
y = awgn(x,snr) //x is your signal vector, y is the signal vector with gaussian noise, and snr is the signal-to-noise ratio in dB
```

For more information: http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/awgn.html

Comment: The restriction of this method is that it requires the communications toolbox.  Some people may not have that luxury.